# Scroll with 'magnetic' effect (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

Is there a way to detect properly if an element is actually on the 'focus' of the scroll...I mean a kind of 'user is now at this element position'?

It would be a kind of comparaison between  `element.offset().top and $(window).scrollTop();` ?

I found this effect on this site (http://andrewgooch.com/mercury-music-awards-2013) and I was ask myself how this could work properly in any device/resolution

Comment: View the source code and find out. And personally I find that effect annoying.

Comment: Yes I try to find out on the code..but it seems very convoluted, they are a lots of function making interaction with the scroll.
I don't like it particulary..they ask me to do it.
Should have been asking for a similar effect not this one in particular.

Comment: -2? You find it so bad this question?
Sorry!

Comment: Not so much a bad question as off-topic the way it's written. SO is intended to be a Q&A resource rather than a help forum. Links are okay for supplementary information, but a full description of the issue should be contained within the question, rather than just posting a link and asking how to reproduce what it points to. The guideline to follow is "Will this still be a useful question-and-answer if my link becomes broken?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He's using:

```
var articles = $('article');

// Find next
function findnext(){
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    articles.each(function() {
        var that = $(this);
        artPosition = that.offset().top;
        if (artPosition > scrollPosition + 10) {
            target = that;
            $.scrollTo(target, 400, {axis:'y', easing:'easeInOutQuart'});
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

etc check the source code